# Laravel 10 api routes returns <span>

Tags: laravel

Laravel 10 with php 8.2 returns sometimes inside data something like 2f0193641c89553e4451d53b5c37f9cc

It happens when I send the same request multiple times to a route. The strange part is that I get 200 status code from the response. The throttle is removed